# Fitting data to a model

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, dataset

I am using the following code with the following data (which I called fn):

**data (fn) here:** https://pastebin.com/WwANBjNx

```
fn = {datneg30, datneg10, dat5, dat25, dat40, dat45, dat50, dat55, 
   dat60, dat65, dat70, dat75, dat80, dat85, dat87, dat90, dat92};
Ta = {-30, -10, 5, 25, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 87, 90,
    92};

Tre = 75 + 273.2;
unagednematic = 0.35;


avnem[t_, T_, h22_, k2ref_, C1_, C2_, n2_] :=
  (h22 - unagednematic) (1 - 
     Exp[-( k2ref Exp[
          C1 (T + 273.2 - Tre)/2.3/Abs[(C2 + T + 273.2 - Tre)]] t^
          n2)])(*Nematic*);

datLC2 = Flatten[
  Table[{fn[[i]][[j, 1]], Ta[[i]], fn[[i]][[j, 3]]}, {i, 13, 15}, {j, 
    1, Length[fn[[i]]]}], 
  1];(*Creates a list of {ta,Ta,LC} from Ta=80C to Ta=87C*)

nlmLC2 = NonlinearModelFit[
  datLC2, {avnem[t, T, h22, k2ref, C1, C2, n2], 0 < h22 < 1.3, 
   0.1 < k2ref < 10, 0 < C1 < C2, 80 > C2 > 0, 
   0.6 < n2 < 1}, {{k2ref, 0.28}, {h22, 1.38}, {C1, 17}, {C2, 
    40}, {n2, 0.75}}, {t, T}];

nlmLC2["RSquared"]
nlmLC2["BestFitParameters"]


fpLC2b = Table[
  nlmLC2[t, Ta[[i]]], {i, 5, 
   15}];(*Reemplace the fitting of nlmLC2 using Ta=40 to Ta=87. Get \
the equation as a function of t only. The 2 at the beginning is the \
index.*)

Show[LogLinearPlot[{fpLC2b}, {t, 0.001, 10000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Purple], Directive[Darker[Yellow]], 
    Directive[Orange]}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[Table[fn[[i]][[All, {1, 5}]], {i, 5, 15}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 13}, AspectRatio -> 1 , 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 87}, {0.14, 
     0.66}]], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1.4}}, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(a\)]\) / s", 16], 
   Style["\[CapitalDelta]H Liquid crystal \
(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Jg\), \(-1\)]\))", 16]}]
```

How can I fit the data to the model of the code (e.g, `h22 - unagednematic) (1 -  Exp[-( k2ref Exp[ C1 (T + 273.2 - Tre)/2.3/Abs[(C2 + T + 273.2 - Tre)]] t^n2)])`)?

I am getting a very bad fitting as the figure show and I know the model should be able to describe the data:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, when plotting, use ``Plot`` and ``ListPlot`` instead of ``LogLinearPlot``and ``ListLogLinearPlot`` – you will see why fitting may have troubles getting the appropriate fit. Secondly, I think your interval for h22 (``0 < h22 < 1.3``) is too small, because in ``avnem`` you subtract the ``unagednematic``. Therefore, the function cannot reach 1.38 in the limit. Thirdly, you may get better results if you fit your function to $\log t$ instead of fitting to $t$.

Answer (score 4):

The primary problem is that the data doesn't fit the model. Let me demonstrate.

**The Data**

When I copied the data from pastebin the first line of the 17th list was a header text so it was deleted.

fn = fn /. fn[[17, 1]] -> Nothing;

Ta = {-30,-10,5,25,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,87,90,92};

I created dataLC for all of the data sorted by Ta and t(s). There were some duplicate (t(s), T) pairs so I further sorted those by LC).

```
dataLC = Flatten[
   Map[
    Module[{iData = #, data, lenData, iTa, lcData},
      data = fn[[iData]];
      iTa = Ta[[iData]];
      lcData = Map[
        Module[{rowData = #},
          {rowData[[1]], iTa, rowData[[3]]}
          ] &,
        data
        ];
      lcData = SortBy[lcData, { #[[1]], #[[3]]} &]
      ] &,
    Range@lengthTa], 1];
```

I formed and plotted constant Ta groups.

```
dataLcTaGroups = GatherBy[dataLC, #[[2]] &];

Labeled[
 ListLogLinearPlot[
  dataLcTaGroups[[All, All, {1, 3}]],
  PlotStyle -> Map[Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Red}, #] &, Subdivide[1, 16]],
  PlotLegends -> Ta,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Joined -> True
  ], "t(s)", Bottom]
```

[image]

**Fit Constant Ta**

One can fit an individual Ta curve to the form given in the problem, but it appears that there is a data offset (approximately 0.35) so I have taken the liberty of adding an offset.

Try the data at Ta = 70 (the highest LC values).

```
fit70 = NonlinearModelFit[
  Select[dataLC, #[[2]] == 70 &][[All, {1, 3}]],
  (h22 - 0.35) (1 - Exp[-scaleTa t^n2]) + offset,
  {h22, scaleTa, n2, offset},
  t
  ]

Show[
 LogLinearPlot[fit70[t], {t, 0.01, 10^4}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListLogLinearPlot[
  Select[dataLC, #[[2]] == 70 &][[All, {1, 3}]],
  PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

**Fit constant t(s)**

Next examine the data plotted with a constant t(s) as a function of Ta. I wrote a little function to take into account the t(s), Ta pairs that had multiple LC values.

```
extractConstantTa[ta_, data_] := Module[
  {dataTa = data[[Position[data, ta][[All, 1]]]], uniqueTa},
  uniqueTa = Union[dataTa[[All, 2]]];
  Map[{#, Mean[dataTa[[Position[dataTa, #][[All, 1]]]][[All, 3]]]} &, 
   uniqueTa]
  ]

dataLc10000 = extractConstantTa[10000., dataLC];
dataLc1000 = extractConstantTa[1000., dataLC];
dataLc100 = extractConstantTa[100., dataLC];
dataLc10 = extractConstantTa[10., dataLC];
dataLc1 = extractConstantTa[1., dataLC];
dataLcP1 = extractConstantTa[0.1, dataLC];
dataLcP01 = extractConstantTa[0.01, dataLC];

Show[
 ListLinePlot[dataLc10000, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListLinePlot[dataLc1000, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListLinePlot[dataLc100, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ListLinePlot[dataLc10, PlotStyle -> Green],
 ListLinePlot[dataLc1, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}],
 ListLinePlot[dataLcP1, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}],
 ListLinePlot[dataLcP01, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Green}]
 ]
```

[image]

Below is the temperature dependence from the model

[image]

There is no combination of constants C1 and C2 that produce a temperature dependance that looks like the plot. It does appear to fit a Gaussian. Let's apply this to the t(s)=10000 data.

```
avnemMuSigma[T_, μ_, σ_, scale_, offset_] := 
 scale * Exp[-((T - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))] + offset

nlmMuSigma10000 = NonlinearModelFit[
  dataLc10000,
  avnemMuSigma[T, μ, σ, scale, offset],
  {
   {μ, 70.0},
   {σ, 10},
   {scale, 3.7},
   {offset, 0.35}
   },
  {T}
  ]

Show[
 ListLinePlot[dataLc10000, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 92}, {0, 3.8}}],
 Plot[nlmMuSigma10000[T], {T, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image]

This appears to fit fine. By doing this repeatedly for the constant t(s) data it becomes clear that μ and σ are linear functions of the log[t]. Below is the list of parameters extracted for the various t(s) fits.

```
parametersMuSigma = {{10000, 69.37, 12.203}, {1000, 70.73, 
    10.637}, {100, 72.64, 9.878}, {10, 75.49, 8.709}, {1, 79.82, 
    7.}, {0.1, 81.7, 6.178}};

fitMu = NonlinearModelFit[
  Map[
   {Log[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &,
   parametersMuSigma
   ],
  m logT + b,
  {m, b},
  logT
  ]

fitSigma = NonlinearModelFit[
  Map[
   {Log[#[[1]]], #[[3]]} &,
   parametersMu
   ],
  m logT + b,
  {m, b},
  logT
  ]

Show[
 LogLinearPlot[{fitMu[Log[t]], fitSigma[Log[t]]},
  {t, 0.01, 10000}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[
  {
   parametersMuSigma[[All, {1, 2}]],
   parametersMuSigma[[All, {1, 3}]]
   },
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

**Complete Model**

```
{mμ, bμ} = {m, b} /. fitMu["BestFitParameters"]
{mσ, bσ} = {m, b} /. fitSigma["BestFitParameters"]

avnemGaussian[t_, T_, h22_, k2ref_, n2_, offset_] := Module[
  {μ = mμ Log[t] + bμ,
   σ = mσ Log[t] + bσ},
  Exp[-((T - μ)^2/(2 σ^2))] (h22 - unagednematic) (1 - 
      Exp[-(k2ref  t^n2)]) + offset
  ]

nlmGaussian = NonlinearModelFit[
  dataLC,
  {
   avnemGaussian[t, T, h22, k2ref, n2, offset]
   },
  {
   {h22, 3.8},
   {k2ref, 0.28},
   {n2, 0.4},
   {offset, 0.35}
   },
  {t, T}
  ]

nlmGaussian["BestFitParameters"]
{h22 -> 3.25059, k2ref -> 0.689558, n2 -> 0.284982, offset -> 0.34247}
```

This is the nlmGaussian plotted for some constant t(s) values

```
Show[
 Plot[nlmGaussian[10000, Ta], {Ta, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[nlmGaussian[1000, Ta], {Ta, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[nlmGaussian[100, Ta], {Ta, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[nlmGaussian[10, Ta], {Ta, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Green],
 Plot[nlmGaussian[1, Ta], {Ta, -30, 92}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

This is the nlmGaussian plotted for some constant Ta values.

```
Labeled[
 LogLinearPlot[
  {nlmGaussian[t, -30], nlmGaussian[t, -10], nlmGaussian[t, 5],
   nlmGaussian[t, 25], nlmGaussian[t, 40], nlmGaussian[t, 45],
   nlmGaussian[t, 50], nlmGaussian[t, 55], nlmGaussian[t, 60],
   nlmGaussian[t, 65], nlmGaussian[t, 70], nlmGaussian[t, 75],
   nlmGaussian[t, 80], nlmGaussian[t, 85], nlmGaussian[t, 87],
   nlmGaussian[t, 90], nlmGaussian[t, 92]},
  {t, 0.01, 10000},
  PlotStyle -> Map[Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Red}, #] &, Subdivide[1, 16]],
  PlotLegends -> Ta,
  PlotRange -> All
  ], "t(s)", Bottom]
```

I leave it to you to compare to the actual data.

[image]